# Where to incorrporate IF and Else if file doesnt exist after os.walk?

Tags: arcpy

How would you skip the arcpy.Merge and arcpy.Clip if 'AAA010.shp' does not exist in the directory that os.walk is going through. I will have more code after the last line in this snippet.

```
import os, fnmatch, arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace  =  r’C:\Users\sysadmin\desktop\datamanagement\MGCP.gdb’

fcMerged = ‘MergedFeatureClass’

fcClipped = ‘ClippedFeatureClass’

fcToClip = r’C:\Users\sysadmin\desktop\datamanagement\Country.shp’

filesMatched = list()

for root, subfolders, files in os.walk(r’C:\Users\sysadmin\desktop\datamanagement\MGCP_Raw’):

  for f in fnmatch.filer(files, ‘AAA010.shp’):
    filesMatched.append(os.path.join(root,f))

if 'AAA010.shp' in filesMatched:

    arcpy.Merge_management (filesMatched, fcMerged)

    arcpy.Clip_analysis (fcMerged, fcToClip, Extraction_Mine)

else: pass
```

Comment: This is both a duplicate and off-topic as not pertaining to GIS.

Comment: I'm curious as to how its unrelated to GIS? Can you shed some light on that @RichardLaw so I know how I should be asking my questions about python.

Comment: I agree with @RichardLaw that this is a duplicate of your previous question and pure Python (i.e. suitable for researching at [so]) because where you are stuck is before using (or at least needing to use) any ArcPy functions. You have set `arcpy.env.workspace` but not accessed that prior to where you are stuck.  For ArcPy help here we really need you to start breaking down your code (and code you find elsewhere) into shorter code snippets that illustrate where you are stuck.  We do not offer a code debugging/writing/improving service but we will help with code snippets.

Comment: I think the way our focussed Q&A format works generally will make a lot more sense if you review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question/3353#3353 and with respect to coding questions if you review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/shortest-code-to-reproduce-gis-programming-problems and http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/tweaking-custom-close-reason-for-poorly-framed-code-debugging-writing-improving

Answer (score 2):

The below code will only perform the merge management and clip analysis if the file name 'AAA010.shp' is in your list after the walk.

```
if 'AAA010.shp' in filesMatched:
    arcpy.Merge_management(filesMatched, fcMerged)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fcMerged, fcToClip, Extraction_Mine)
else: pass
```

This of course assumes all your variables used in the merge and clip have been set up correctly.

Comment: Note, this will also work without the else statement.

Comment: @nwduncan I just ran it, and it completely skipped over the merge and clip even though a .shp exists

Comment: @BrianJ After you run the walk, print out the resulting list. What's in the list?

Comment: All of the .shp that should be merging together.

Comment: Can you paste in exactly what is printed out so we can see?

Comment: I'm not sure how to print the list. Also, it is difficult for me to copy past anything from my work computer to this computer since it is not able to connect to normal internet.

Comment: OK. The above code will only work if the string 'AAA010.shp' is in the list. Remember, strings are case sensitive when truth testing in python. For example, 'aaa010.shp' or 'AAA010.SHP' are not the same as 'AAA010.shp'. Make sure the string you're testing for is in the list exactly as in the if statement.

Comment: It looks like in your code the resulting list will be filled with strings containing the full path name of your shape files. Testing for 'AAA010.shp' will not return True. I would consult the answers to your previous question as they seem to answer it quite well.

Comment: 'AAA010.shp' does exist. Without the If and Else the code does what it is supposed to do